# PySpark: when function with multiple outputs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use a "chained when" function.
In other words, I'd like to get more than two outputs.

I tried using the same logic of the concatenate IF function in Excel:

```
  df.withColumn("device_id", when(col("device")=="desktop",1)).otherwise(when(col("device")=="mobile",2)).otherwise(null))
```

But that doesn't work since I can't put a tuple into the "otherwise" function.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn('device_id', F.when(col('device')=='desktop', 1).when(col('device')=='mobile', 2).otherwise(None))
```

Note that when chaining `when` functions you do not need to wrap the successive calls in an `otherwise` function.

Comment: Super useful the `when` chaining composition! Thanks!

Comment: These are chained operations - if multiple when() are true, does the variable get assigned the first condition that is True or the last one?

Comment: @Thomas If multiple consecutive when() statements are true, only the first when() evaluated to true is considered.