# Pyspark: Equivalent of np.where

Tags: pandas, pyspark

What is the equivalent of this operation in Pyspark?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Type':list('ABBC'), 'Set':list('ZZXY')})
df['color'] = np.where(df['Set']=='Z', 'green', 'red')
print(df)
```

**output**

```
   Set Type  color
0   Z    A  green
1   Z    B  green
2   X    B    red
3   Y    C    red
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're looking for [`pyspark.sql.functions.when()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when):

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col

df = df.withColumn('color', when(col('Set') == 'Z', 'green').otherwise('red'))
df.show()
#+---+----+-----+
#|Set|Type|color|
#+---+----+-----+
#|  Z|   A|green|
#|  Z|   B|green|
#|  X|   B|  red|
#|  Y|   C|  red|
#+---+----+-----+
```

If you have multiple conditions to check, you can chain together calls to `when()` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42537653/5858851).

Comment: Thanks, you are the best :)

Comment: This account I don't have enough reputation, but I did it with my other account.