# Pyspark create new column based if a column isin another Spark Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, rdd, data-wrangling

I am trying to create a column in my Spark Dataframe a flag if a column's row is in a separate Dataframe.

This is my main Spark Dataframe (`df_main`)

```
+--------+
|main    |
+--------+
|28asA017|
|03G12331|
|1567L044|
|02TGasd8|
|1asd3436|
|A1234567|
|B1234567|
+--------+
```

This is my reference (`df_ref`), there are hundreds of rows in this reference so I obviously can't hard code them like this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048229/spark-equivalent-of-if-then-else) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539830/pyspark-equivalent-of-np-where)

```
+--------+
|mask_vl |
+--------+
|A1234567|
|B1234567|
...
+--------+
```

Normally, what I'd do in pandas' dataframe is this:

```
df_main['is_inref'] = np.where(df_main['main'].isin(df_ref.mask_vl.values), "YES", "NO")
```

So that I would get this

```
+--------+--------+
|main |is_inref|
+--------+--------+
|28asA017|NO      |
|03G12331|NO      |
|1567L044|NO      |
|02TGasd8|NO      |
|1asd3436|NO      |
|A1234567|YES     |
|B1234567|YES     |
+--------+--------+
```

I have tried the following code, but I don't get what the error in the picture means.

```
df_main = df_main.withColumn('is_inref', "YES" if F.col('main').isin(df_ref) else "NO")
df_main.show(20, False)
```

[image: Error of the mentioned code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. I think the additional step that you need, is to explicitly create the list that will contain the values from `df_ref`.

Please see below an illustration:

```
# Create your DataFrames
df = spark.createDataFrame(["28asA017","03G12331","1567L044",'02TGasd8','1asd3436','A1234567','B1234567'], "string").toDF("main")
df_ref =  spark.createDataFrame(["A1234567","B1234567"], "string").toDF("mask_vl")
```

Then, you can create a `list` and use `isin`, almost as you have it:

```
# Imports
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

# Create a list with the values of your reference DF
mask_vl_list = df_ref.select("mask_vl").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

# Use isin to check whether the values in your column exist in the list
df_main = df_main.withColumn('is_inref', when(col('main').isin(mask_vl_list), 'YES').otherwise('NO'))
```

---

This will give you:

```
>>> df_main.show()

+--------+--------+
|    main|is_inref|
+--------+--------+
|28asA017|      NO|
|03G12331|      NO|
|1567L044|      NO|
|02TGasd8|      NO|
|1asd3436|      NO|
|A1234567|     YES|
|B1234567|     YES|
+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @sophocles. Am I correct to understand that the first command (the rdd.flatMap(...).collect()) is to basically convert the dataframe into a list into the main driver node? If so, won't I run into an out of memory exception if the reference becomes huge ?

Comment: Welcome. Yes you are right. I don't think that you will run into memory exception problems as this is an efficient approach. You can check out more information [```here```](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38610559/convert-spark-dataframe-column-to-python-list) about performance benchmarking to convert a column to a list.

Comment: I guess that collect() is not the best solution. If the mask_v1 data frame will grow, it will be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid collect, I advise you to do the next:

```
df_ref= df_ref
          .withColumnRenamed("mask_v1", "main")
          .withColumn("isPreset", lit("yes"))
      
 main_df= main_df.join(df_ref, Seq("main"), "left_outer")
          .withColumn("is_inref", when(col("isPresent").isNull,
          lit("NO")).otherwise(lit("YES")))
```