# how to match 2 column with each other in Apache Spark - Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe so assume my data is in Tabular format.

```
|ID   |       Serial               |    Updated
-------------------------------------------------------
|10   |pers1                       |                  |
|20   |                            |                  |
|30   |entity_1, entity_2, entity_3|entity_1, entity_3|
```

Now using withColumn("Serial", explode(split(",")"Serial"))). I have achieved breaking columns into multiple rows as below. this was the 1st part of the requirement.

```
   |ID   |       Serial    |    Updated
    -------------------------------------------------------
    |10   |pers1           |                  |
    |20   |                |                  |
    |30   |entity_1        |entity_1, entity_3|
    |30   |entity_2        |entity_1, entity_3|
    |30   |entity_3        |entity_1, entity_3|
```

Now for the columns where there are no values it should be 0,
For values which is present in **'Serial'** Column should be searched in **'Updated'** column. If the value is present in '**Updated**' column then it should display '1' else '2'

So for here in this case for entity_1  && entity_3  --> 1 must be displayed & for entity_2  --> 2 should be displayed

How to achieve this ..?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to check if one column is contained within or is a substring of another column directly without using a `udf`.

However, if you wanted to avoid using a `udf`, one way is to explode the `"Updated"` column. Then you can check for equality between the `"Serial"` column and the exploded `"Updated"` column and apply your conditions (1 if match, 2 otherwise)- call this `"contains"`.

Finally, you can then `groupBy("ID", "Serial", "Updated")` and select the minimum of the `"contains"` column.

For example, after the two calls to `explode()` and checking your condition, you will have a DataFrame like this:

```python
df.withColumn("Serial", f.explode(f.split("Serial", ",")))\
    .withColumn("updatedExploded", f.explode(f.split("Updated", ",")))\
    .withColumn(
        "contains",
        f.when(
            f.isnull("Serial") | 
            f.isnull("Updated") | 
            (f.col("Serial") == "") | 
            (f.col("Updated") == ""),
            0
        ).when(
            f.col("Serial") == f.col("updatedExploded"),
            1
        ).otherwise(2)
    )\
    .show(truncate=False)
#+---+--------+-----------------+---------------+--------+
#|ID |Serial  |Updated          |updatedExploded|contains|
#+---+--------+-----------------+---------------+--------+
#|10 |pers1   |                 |               |0       |
#|20 |        |                 |               |0       |
#|30 |entity_1|entity_1,entity_3|entity_1       |1       |
#|30 |entity_1|entity_1,entity_3|entity_3       |2       |
#|30 |entity_2|entity_1,entity_3|entity_1       |2       |
#|30 |entity_2|entity_1,entity_3|entity_3       |2       |
#|30 |entity_3|entity_1,entity_3|entity_1       |2       |
#|30 |entity_3|entity_1,entity_3|entity_3       |1       |
#+---+--------+-----------------+---------------+--------+
```

The "trick" of grouping by `("ID", "Serial", "Updated")` and taking the minimum of `"contains"` works because:

- If either `"Serial"` or `"Updated"` is null (or equal to empty string in this case), the value will be 0.
- If at least one of the values in `"Updated"` matches with `"Serial"`, one of the columns will have a 1.
- If there are no matches, you will have only 2's

The final output:

```python
df.withColumn("Serial", f.explode(f.split("Serial", ",")))\
    .withColumn("updatedExploded", f.explode(f.split("Updated", ",")))\
    .withColumn(
        "contains",
        f.when(
            f.isnull("Serial") |
            f.isnull("Updated") |
            (f.col("Serial") == "") |
            (f.col("Updated") == ""),
            0
        ).when(
            f.col("Serial") == f.col("updatedExploded"),
            1
        ).otherwise(2)
    )\
    .groupBy("ID", "Serial", "Updated")\
    .agg(f.min("contains").alias("contains"))\
    .sort("ID")\
    .show(truncate=False)
#+---+--------+-----------------+--------+
#|ID |Serial  |Updated          |contains|
#+---+--------+-----------------+--------+
#|10 |pers1   |                 |0       |
#|20 |        |                 |0       |
#|30 |entity_3|entity_1,entity_3|1       |
#|30 |entity_2|entity_1,entity_3|2       |
#|30 |entity_1|entity_1,entity_3|1       |
#+---+--------+-----------------+--------+
```

I'm [chaining calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537051/pyspark-when-function-with-multiple-outputs) to [`pyspark.sql.functions.when()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) to check the conditions. The first part checks to see if either column is `null` or equal to the empty string. I believe that you probably only need to check for `null` in your actual data, but I put in the check for empty string based on how you displayed your example DataFrame.