# how to modify one column value in one row used by pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I want to update  value when userid=22650984.How to do it in pyspark platform?thank you for helping.

```
>>>xxDF.select('userid','registration_time').filter('userid="22650984"').show(truncate=False)
18/04/08 10:57:00 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 57.0 (TID 874, shopee-hadoop-slave89, executor 9): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
18/04/08 10:57:00 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 11.1 in stage 57.0 (TID 875, shopee-hadoop-slave97, executor 16): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
+--------+----------------------------+
|userid  |registration_time           |
+--------+----------------------------+
|22650984|270972-04-26 13:14:46.345152|
+--------+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use [`withColumn`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn) to achieve what you are looking to do:

```
new_df = xxDf.filter(xxDf.userid = "22650984").withColumn(xxDf.field_to_update, <update_expression>)
```

the update_expression would have your logic for update - could be UDF, or derived field, etc..

Comment: This will not work for two reasons: 1) you need to use == instead of = because you're comparing values not assigning, 2) when using == it will filter out the rest of the df, when the user only wants to change one row

Comment: working code:

from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
new_df = xxDf.filter(xxDf.userid == "22650984").withColumn('column_to update', lit(<update_expression>)

Answer (score 31):

If you want to modify a subset of your DataFrame and keep the rest unchanged, the best option would be to use [`pyspark.sql.functions.when()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) as using `filter` or [`pyspark.sql.functions.where()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.where) would remove all rows where the condition is not met.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

valueWhenTrue = None  # for example

df.withColumn(
    "existingColumnToUpdate",
    when(
        col("userid") == 22650984,
        valueWhenTrue
    ).otherwise(col("existingColumnToUpdate"))
)
```

When will evaluate the first argument as a boolean condition. If the condition is `True`, it will return the second argument. You can chain together multiple `when` statements as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048229/spark-equivalent-of-if-then-else) and also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537051/pyspark-when-function-with-multiple-outputs). Or use [`otherwise()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.otherwise) to specify what to do when the condition is `False`.

In this example, I am updating an existing column `"existingColumnToUpdate"`. When the `userid` is equal to the specified value, I will update the column with `valueWhenTrue`. Otherwise, we will keep the value in the column unchanged.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! This approach is very similar to Pandas style. Different but understandable to those who Panda...

Answer (score 0):

Change Value of a Dataframe Column Based on a Filter:

`from pyspark.sql.functions import lit new_df = xxDf.filter(xxDf.userid == "22650984").withColumn('clumn_to update', lit(<update_expression>)`